# catkin_make_isolated builds tf after a package that requires tf?

Tags: ros, catkin-make-isolated

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building ROS on a Raspberry Pi 3 using catkin_make_isolated. The full command is `sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo -j2`.

I have a package that requires tf, but when using the above command, tf is built after the package, and so the whole make fails.

When building without the new package, the make finishes fine.

Any ideas? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248726/catkin_make_isolated-builds-tf-after-a-package-that-requires-tf?/) by [DM2](https://answers.ros.org/users/27473/dm2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-11-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-24**:
Please include the `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` of the package that "requires tf". Make sure to remove all the boilerplate comments from them though (especially `CMakeList.txt`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for helping! I actually went over the CMakeLists.txt myself afterwards and after removing all the junk found the problem myself. I solved it by removing a non existing add_executable that was left over from the download off github. Maybe I should notify the guys who uploaded it.

---

Originally posted by [DM2](https://answers.ros.org/users/27473/dm2/) with karma: 26 on 2016-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-28**:
re: "notify the guys": yes, you should.